# Replace '\' character in python

Tags: python, string

I don't know why i can't find it, but i wanted to replace the special character `'\'` in python.

I have a String within i have `'\'` characters but i confident find the solution, to replace it with '-'.
This is what happening while i am trying to replace,

```
>>> x = 'hello\world'
>>> x
'hello\\world'
>>> x.replace('\', '-')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x.replace('\', '-')
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

**EDIT:**
Do try this it in the eclipse IDLE

```
x = 'hello\world'
print x
x.replace('\\', '-')
print x
```

Output:

```
hello\world
hello\world
```

Comment: Escape backslash : `'hello\\world'.replace('\\', '-')`

Comment: @Heliconia: `replace` doesn't change the string, it returns a new one.  What you need to say is `x = x.replace('\\', '-')`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape it with another backslash:

```
 x.replace('\\', '-')
```

Backslashes are special, in that they are used to introduce non-printing characters like newlines into a string.

It's also how you add a `'` character to a `'`-quoted string, which is what Python thinks you were trying to do.  It sees `\'` and interprets as a literal quote within the string, rather than letting the `'` end the string.  Then it gets to the end of the string and finds `EOL` ("end of line") before the end of the string.

To introduce a *real* backslash, you need to double it.  You can see that Python itself did this when printing the representation of your initial string here:

```
>>> x
'hello\\world'
```

Note the double backslash.

You ought to use a double backslash when specifying your string in the first place.  The reason that doesn't need it is that `\w` is not a special character, so it gets interpreted as a literal backslash and a `w`.  Had you said `'Hello\now'` you would have a string with a newline in it.

You could have also marked the string as a "raw" string by prepending it with `r` as in `r'hello\world'`. This marks the string as not being eligible for any substitutions of special characters.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character.

You need to escape backslash with another backslash:

```
x.replace('\\', '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

This `\'` is interpreted as a special character. Escape it:

```
x.replace('\\', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

in python your string 
    x = 'hello\world'
    is replaced as x = "hello\world"

so to achieve u have to write

```
x.replace('\\','-')
```